# If I have 2 lists in a dictionary, how to append both of them at once?

Tags: python, dictionary, pygame

```
    self.W = {}
    self.W[A] = {'x':[], 'y':[]}
```

I want to do the following:

```
   self.W[A]['x'].append(X)
```

and:

```
   self.W[A]['y'].append(Y),
```

at once.

How to do both in one command?

## Edit:

Let me write it in more clear way:

```
WEAPONS = {}
WEAPONS['launcher'] = {'idle_img' : [ "pic1.png", "pic2.png", "pic3.png"],
                       'shoot_img' : ['img1.png', 'img2.png', 'img3.png'],
              

                   

WEAPONS['pistol']  =  {'idle_img' : [ "another_pic1.png", "another_pic2.png",'another_pic3'],
                       'shoot_img' : ['another_img1.png', 'you know.png', 'abcxyz.png']}
```

now I have another `dict`:

```
self.another_dict = {}
self.another_dict['launcher'] = {'idle_img' : [],
                                 'shoot_img' : [],
              

                   

self.another_dict['pistol']  =  {'idle_img' : [],
                                 'shoot_img' : []}
```

Now, I want to add those images in `WEAPONS['pistol']['idle_img']` to `self.another_dict['pistol']['idle_img']`

also do it with ['shoot_img'] (and a lot of ['something_img'] like that too).I can do that one by one :

```
for l in WEAPONS:
        for i in self.WEAPONS[l]['idle_img']:
          self.another_dict[l]['idle_img'].append(i)
```

but that kind of long if I do that for all those ['   _img']

So, I assume there must be a way to do them at once, or there will be a lot of writing.

Comment: Can you please explain your question. Is it like W is a dictionary having a key A and value {'x':[], 'y':[]} which is again a dictionary?

Comment: i made it more clear in edit part

Answer (score 1):

I think you might find `dict().from_keys()` helpful.

```
W = {}.fromkeys(['x', 'y'], [])

W['x'].append('hello')
```

```
{'x': ['hello'], 'y': ['hello']}
```

It creates a dictionary with the provided keys, and their default values are the same object (if mutable). So, appending one will append the other. But be careful, they really do point to the same object so you'll have to do extra steps to treat them separately in the future.

Answer (score 0):

ah damn, I cant believe I use loop twice but dont use it again. here is how I solve it:

```
for l in WEAPONS:
  for t in self.another_dict[l]
    for i in self.WEAPONS[l][t]:
      self.another_dict[l][t].append(i)
```

thx for all the answer